# add product to zen cart website from external campaign site

Tags: php, zen-cart

I am having a campaign site and would like to find the way for customers selecting products on my campaign site and send the product information to my zen cart site and add those items to cart directly. Therefore, customers no need to select the products again in zen cart site, by any chance,anyone would know how to do? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the cart accepts POST data so you'd have to make a POST form on your campaign site with the product IDs as hidden fields and a submit button sending the customer to your site; there's an example here:

```
<form name="cart_quantity" action="http://www.company.com/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&amp;action=add_product" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="hidden" name="cart_quantity" value="1" />

<input type="hidden" name="products_id" value="1" />

<input type="image" src="yourimage.png" alt="Add to Cart" title=" Add to Cart " />
```

which is found on this thread:

http://www.zen-cart.com/showthread.php?96857-Add-to-cart-link

Comment: The new Zen Cart requires a <input type="hidden" name="securityToken" value="">. The challenge now is getting that token and inserting it into the form.